# JDeveloper imports troubles

Tags: java, deployment, jar, ejb, jdeveloper

I'm trying to get `jar` file using `JDeveloper` from EJB project, but every time I want to run, deploy or  debug I catch imports exceptions. Like this:

```
cannot find class HttpServletRequest
cannot find class HttpServletResponse
package javax.ejb does not exist
```

and etc. After `organize imports` nothing is changed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the JAR that you added is marked to be included in deploy.
If you add this as a library there is a check box at the library level to say include in deployment.